# Landscape mode causes a blankpage

Tags: page-breaking, landscape

I'm using this code for showing an image in landscape mode:

```
\begin{landscape}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{./images/SelectDVA.png}
\caption{DVA part of the Use Case \ref{sec:use_case_2}.}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
```

This causes the output to have a blank page immediately after the rotated page containing the image.

It seems that using landscape causes a page break, is it true?

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: `landscape` won't leave a blank page but it causes a page break. You can use `afterpage` to avoid the white space produced thereby.

Comment: Never ever include a `figure` in `landscape`!

Comment: @StephanLehmke Why not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`landscape` will not produce blank pages but cause a page break where it is introduced. This will result in undesired white space in the previous page. This can be avoided by using the `afterpage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
\caption{DVA part of the Use Case \ref{sec:use_case_2}.}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
}
\lipsum[3-8]

\end{document}
```

If you use `pdflscape` instead of `lscape` package,

[image]

Comment: can you explain me what is the `\lipsum` command doing?thks in advance

Comment: @Matteo It's just filler http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipsum

Comment: This isn't working for me. I still have a blank page before the landscape figure. The code was used exactly as in the example above, except that I am using package 'pdflscape'.

Comment: @cryptic0 Not working isn't useful enough. This code works for me.

Comment: I am using this code for a landscape figure.  The only change I have made is using pdflscape package which actually rotates the page to landscape mode.  However, there is still a blank page before every landscape figure.

Comment: @cryptic0 See what I get above with `pdflscape`. That is why the above comment :)

Comment: There must be some other package that is interfering in my case then. I will investigate.

Comment: The problem is related to the size of the figure.  Even if it fits on one page, it might still result in a blank page.  I scaled down the figure gradually until the blank page went away.  FYI.

Answer (score 13):

A blank page can be caused by the figure (or table, etc) within the landscape environment exceeding the dimensions of the page's `textwidth` or `textheight`. In this case, we can manually define the page margins with `\newgeometry{}` and then revert back to the document default with`\restoregeometry`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

% Set some new page margins:
\newgeometry{a4paper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,nohead}
\begin{landscape}
     % figure, etc
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry % Restore the global document page margins

\end{document}
```

Or you can do it with `\savegeometry{name}` and `\loadgeometry{name}`. See http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PierPaolo. I have read the article countless times, but for the life of me I don't understand which specific policy you and your upvoter believe I have not followed. Please explain.

Comment: I tried this and it generated an additional blank page!

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked this simple solution? I had a big, page-filling table and the `landscape` environment caused a blank page before the table. I noticed that the option `[H]` in `\begin{table}[H]` caused the blank page. If you use `\begin{table}[htbp]` instead, the annoying blank page is gone. `[H]` is useful to place the tables exactly where you position the command, but in conjunction with the `landscape` environment it is unnecessary.

Example:

```
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}    
% some text    
\begin{landscape}    
\thispagestyle{empty} %if you want to suppress footer and header    
\begin{table}[htbp]    
...    
\end{table}    
\end{landscape}    
% continue with your text    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: To rotate pages with `\usepackage{pdflscape}` or `\usepackage{lscape}` in a document generated with bookdown/R markdown, this was the only viable solution that worked for me. I.e., adding `fig.pos = 'htbp'` to the chunk header of my figure made the obsolete blank white landscape page *before* the landscape page with the figure magically disappear.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple solution is turn 90° the content of a normal float (without `[H]`) using only normal (portrait) pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}
\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{DVA part of the Use Case.}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-7]
\end{document}
```

> [image: MWE]

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem as you. I have a landscape environment followed by a figure environment. The landscape environment introduces a blank page between the landscape environment and the figure environment. I solve this issue by accidentally changing \begin{figure} to \begin{figure}[H]. Have no idea why ...... but it works! I got the idea from this post: [How to remove a blank page before landscape figure tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319662/how-to-remove-a-blank-page-before-landscape-figure-tabular) where they said removing [H] works, but for me adding [H] works.

Answer (score 0):

I like [this answer's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223780/38074) approach of simply minimizing page margins.
However, I am using KOMAScript and the `geometry` package doesn't seem to work well with it (as far as I know!).
Thus, here's a hopefully KOMAScript-idiomatic way that worked for me:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \storeareas\normalpapersize%
}
\BeforeRestoreareas{\cleardoublepage}

\begin{document}

  % set some new page margins
  \KOMAoptions{DIV=16}
  \recalctypearea
  \begin{landscape}
    % figure, etc
  \end{landscape}
  \normalpapersize

\end{document}
```