# How to remove a blank page before landscape figure tabular?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, tabularx, landscape

I tried to insert a figure using `landscape`, `figure` and `tabular`. However, it has an extra blank page. What should I do to remove the extra page?

Thank you so much.[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}`enter code here`
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}   
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 


\makeatletter
\makeatother
\geometry{left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.0in}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \advance\leftskip-1cm
 \caption{Title}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel A} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{a} &
   \\
         \multicolumn{3}{c}{Panel B} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{a} &
  \end{tabular}
 \floatfoot{\textit{Notes:} This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.This is a note.}
 \label{a}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: I figure out myself!!! Just remove the [H] after \begin{figure}. Yeah!

Comment: The figure is better centred with  the `sidewaysfigure` environment.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you wish.