# Incompatibility between rotfloat and hyperref?

Tags: floats, hyperref, rotating, landscape, afterpage

Latex is  creating a blank page before a sideways table. Initially, I thought this was a problem with sideways table (see [Landscape mode causes a blankpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84506/landscape-mode-causes-a-blankpage)). Indeed the blank page goes away if I use any of the solutions proposed on that page (i.e., the afterpage package or removing the "H" float placement). However, I need the tables, as well as the section headings, *exactly* where they appear on the document. If I use either solution, then stuff moves around.

Then, during my several attempts to create a replicable example, I discovered that, by removing hyperref, the problem goes away. According to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before), the float package should be loaded before hyperref. It doesn't say anything about rotfloat, though. Is there any incompatibility between the two? (Needless to say, I can't simply remove hyperref from the document altogether, as I need it elsewhere.)

### Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}
\subsubsection{First Sub-Subsection Heading}
\begin{table}[H] \centering 
  \caption{A smallish table} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 1} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 2} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 3} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 4} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 5} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 6} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 7} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 8} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{A note} \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Another note} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[H] \centering 
  \caption{another  smallish table} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 1} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 2} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 3} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 4} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 5} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 6} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 7} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 8} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{A note} \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Another note} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\subsubsection{Second Sub-Subsection Heading}
\begin{sidewaystable}[H] \centering 
  \caption{A very large table} 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table heading} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 6} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading for columns 1-3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading for columns 4-6} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
  Row 1 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 2 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 3 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 4 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 5 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 6 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 7 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 8 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 9 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 10 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 11 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 12 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 13 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 14 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 15 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 16 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 17 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 18 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 19 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 20 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 21 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 22 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 23 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 24 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 25 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 26 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{A note} \\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Another note} \\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Yet another note} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV2eh.png).

### The problem goes away if I don't load hyperref

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Heading}
\subsection{Subsection Heading}
\subsubsection{First Sub-Subsection Heading}
\begin{table}[H] \centering 
  \caption{A smallish table} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 1} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 2} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 3} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 4} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 5} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 6} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 7} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 8} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{A note} \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Another note} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[H] \centering 
  \caption{another  smallish table} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 1} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 2} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 3} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 4} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 5} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 6} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 7} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Row 8} & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{A note} \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Another note} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\subsubsection{Second Sub-Subsection Heading}
\begin{sidewaystable}[H] \centering 
  \caption{A very large table} 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Table heading} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 6} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column subheading} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading for columns 1-3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading for columns 4-6} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
  Row 1 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 2 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 3 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 4 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 5 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 6 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 7 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 8 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 9 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 10 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 11 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 12 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 13 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 14 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 15 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 16 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 17 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 18 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 19 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 20 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 21 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 22 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 23 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 24 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 25 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  Row 26 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{A note} \\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Another note} \\ 
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Yet another note} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvVk6.png).

Comment: It is simply wrong to use the `[H]` placement specifier with a `sidewaystable` environment. Don't do it, and the all-empty page disappears -- irrespective of whether or not the `hyperref` package is loaded. If you want the table to show up on the same page as the subsubsection-level header, don't use a `sidewaystable` environment; instead, use a `sideways` environment.

Comment: "It is simply wrong to use the [H] placement specifier with a sidewaystable environment." Source? If that was the case, why would the developers even bother creating rotfloat?

Comment: I didn't wrote the `rotfloat` package to combine `rotating` package and `[H]`, instead I wrote it to combine `rotating` and floats defined with `\newfloat` offered by the `float` package. I second the statement from Mico, it's wrong to use `[H]` with a `sidewaystable` environment... However, using `[H]` with sideways-floats could make sense in special situations, for example when combining it with `\afterpage` offered by the `afterpage` package.

Comment: @LucasDeAbreuMaia - Question: Source? Answer: Please study the user guide of the `rotating` package -- and especially its section 5, "Sideways figures and tables". You'll learn, *inter alia*, that the `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` environments are meant to occupy an entire page at a time. If you try to shoehorn a subsubsection-level header onto a page with a `sidewaystable` environment (via the `[H]` specifier), you'll necessarily get a massively overfull page -- as indeed your code does.

Comment: @Nico, the sideways environment, in addition to making the font size \tiny, did the trick. I still do not understand why loading hyperref results in a blank page, but if you want to offer the sideways environment suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @David Carlisle, as you can read in the alt tag for the images, I'm blind. I apologize but I naturally had no idea that (1) the PNG was made into a gif and (2) it was uncomfortable. I will remove the images and simply link to the outputs in case someone wants to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is overfull, you get a warning

```
Overfull \vbox (33.08087pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Such overfull page are always in danger of creating empty pages: Often LaTeX pushes them one page later to try if they fit there.

You can enlarge the page:

```
\subsubsection{Second Sub-Subsection Heading}\enlargethispage{40pt}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why the blank page only appears when I load hyperref.

Comment: Well hyperref does a lot of small things that affect typesetting, in this case the effect disappear if one disables raiselinks with `\def\Hy@raisedlink#1{}`. But I don't want to spent my time hunting down what exactly happens.